# Client libraries available for Flutter/Dart?

Tags: transaction, iota-network, legacy-protocol

Probably not typically needed for an IoT device, but a general app that uses the Iota ledger might be on a mobile device, and the Flutter framework seems pretty handy (I like how it can output iOS and Android code, and probably by now, the browser). And I would think there would be many use-cases for mobile devices. Live search results presented when typing this suggest that access is through REST calls, so it sounds like a Dart wrapper wouldn't be that hard (I just don't now how to do that). So might there be any plans to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Dart. In most languages you are able to write your library in C and create an API in the target language. So, you should take a look into the [iota.c](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.c) library and wrap it in Dart, if possible.

Comment: OK, thanks. That's kind of what I thought I would have to do. I had looked into this method in the past when I looked at other Flutter packages calling/wrapping iOS-specific functions. It looked like it might have been tricky in aligning/matching data types, but I'll take a look at what might be needed.